reposition checkbox in Tkinter
I have the below code -
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox


def main():
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()


class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Simple App")
        self.geometry('800x500')

        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Blank space top left
        frame1 = tk.Frame(self)
        frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

        # Frame containing the 4 buttons
        frame2 = Buttons(self)
        frame2.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="nswe", padx=5, pady=5)

        # Frame containing the first check boxes
        frame3 = Checkbox(self)
        frame3.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nswe", padx=5, pady=5)

        # Frame for next check boxes
        # frame4 = HandleCheckBox(self)
        # frame4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nswe", padx=5, pady=5)


class Buttons(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.entry_btn = ttk.Button(self, text="Add")
        self.entry_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.entry_btn2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Clear")
        self.entry_btn2.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.entry_btn3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Continue")
        self.entry_btn3.grid(row=0, column=2)

        self.entry_btn4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Finish")
        self.entry_btn4.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=3, sticky='nsew')


class Checkbox(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.checkbox_dict = {}  # Stores INT VAR
        self.second_checkbox_dict = {}  # Stores INT VAR for second boxes
        self.checkbox_list = []  # Stores WIDGET
        self.destroy_second_checkbox = {}  # Stores widgets for destruction
        self.row = 0
        self.second_row = 0

        for key in dict1.keys():
            self.checkbox_list.append(self.create_check_box(key))

    def create_check_box(self, dict_key):
        int_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)  # Set initial value to 0 (unchecked)
        checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text=dict_key, variable=int_var,
                                      command=lambda: self.check_state(dict_key))

        checkbutton.grid(row=self.row, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.checkbox_dict[dict_key] = int_var
        self.row += 1
        return checkbutton

    def check_state(self, key):
        state = self.checkbox_dict[key].get()
        if state == 1:
            self.destroy_second_checkbox[key] = []
            for value in dict1[key]:
                int_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)  # Set initial value to 0 (unchecked)
                checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text=value, variable=int_var)
                self.second_checkbox_dict[value] = int_var
                checkbutton.grid(row=self.second_row, column=1, sticky='w')
                self.destroy_second_checkbox[key].append(checkbutton)
                self.second_row += 1

        else:
            for widget in self.destroy_second_checkbox[key]:
                widget.destroy()





dict1 = {'item1': ['Lang1', 'Lang11'], 'item2': ['Lang2', 'Lang22'], 'item3': ['Lang3', 'Lang33']}
main()

which produces this window -

When I check the boxes labelled "ITEM1, 2, 3" More checkboxes pop up like this -

However, when the ITEM boxes are unchecked and then checked again the order doesn't remain the same and it appears to ignore the Row variables, I'm aware that the self.second_row variable isn't resetting or changing.
Is there anything I can do to ensure that when the ITEM boxes are checked the relevant values "LANG" are placed in a specific area and not randomly moved about?

Instead of creating and destroying the checkbuttons each time, you could just make them once, put them in the row you want and use grid_remove() and grid() to make them disappear and reappear whenever you want. See this for a simple example.

As said in the comment, you don't need to destroy and re-create those checkboxes in column 1.  Simply create them initially and show them based on the state of the checkboxes in column 0.
Below is the modified class Checkbox:
class Checkbox(ttk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.checkbox_dict = {}  # Stores IntVar for first column
        self.second_checkbox_dict = {}  # Stores IntVar and Checkbutton for second column

        for row, key in enumerate(dict1):
            self.create_check_box(row, key)

    def create_check_box(self, row, dict_key):
        int_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)  # Set initial value to 0 (unchecked)
        checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text=dict_key, variable=int_var,
                                      command=lambda: self.check_state(dict_key))

        checkbutton.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky='w')
        self.checkbox_dict[dict_key] = int_var

        # create corresponding checkboxes for column 1
        for value in dict1[dict_key]:
            int_var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
            checkbutton = ttk.Checkbutton(self, text=value, variable=int_var)
            self.second_checkbox_dict[value] = (int_var, checkbutton)

    def check_state(self, dict_key):
        row = 0
        for key, int_var in self.checkbox_dict.items():
            for value in dict1[key]:
                int_var_2, widget = self.second_checkbox_dict[value]
                if int_var.get():
                    widget.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='w')
                    row += 1
                else:
                    widget.grid_forget()
                    #int_var_2.set(0) # clear the checkbox if you want

